# Search excel range for a specific column matching todays date

Tags: excel, date, formula, textjoin

My Excel formula searches for a range of cells and cell that matches the date is outputted in a separate cell. That cell contains the function below. What I would like to do is instead of displaying every individual cell I would like to just display the column name that matches the date. So instead of e4,e5,e6. I would like it to just state e.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF($1:$19=TODAY(),ADDRESS(ROW($1:$19),COLUMN($1:$19),4),""))
```

Comment: Will your data ever go further than column Z?

Comment: yes it can not and at column z